# MongoDB How to use $not, $and/$or with $type?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have different data types for the same field name `f`

with [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/) reference,

i want to find all records that are not `Double` and are not `NULL`

i'm able to find the records that are not `Double` by

```
db.foo.find({ f:{$not:{$type:1}} })
```

but can not combine the query with not `NULL`

tried with

```
db.foo.find({f:{$not:{$and:[{$type:1},{$type:10}]}}})'
db.foo.find({$and:[{f:{$not:{$type:1}}}, {f:{$not:{$type:10}}}] })
```

but that fails

any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a [$nor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) condition

```js
db.foo.find({ $nor:[ { f: {$type:1} }, { f: null }] })
```

Which means **none** of the included arguments are true. Also not the simplified usage of finding a `null` value.

Comment: @StephenTalari All the documentation sits around the same place. The site just got a facelift so the navigation is a bit funky, but the breadcrumb should work for you here. The $and and $or operators have a similar syntax and **wrap** the conditions in an array. $nor is appropriate where you wanted to apply a $not condition to several elements. For other wrapping methods, just add them into the find as an additional argument. According to your needs.